# Grant readaccess to all existing (and future) Postgres schematas

Tags: postgresql, roles

I have a Postgres database (PostgreSQL-Version 11), which has a lot schematas. Each schemata has a lot of tables. So, now I've got a user xyz, which should have readaccess to all of those schematas and all future ones. I found [this](https://gist.github.com/oinopion/4a207726edba8b99fd0be31cb28124d0) gist, which explains how to create a readaccess group and how to add a user to this group:

```
-- Create a group
CREATE ROLE readaccess;

-- Grant access to existing tables
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO readaccess;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO readaccess;

-- Grant access to future tables
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO readaccess;

-- Create a final user with password
CREATE USER tomek WITH PASSWORD 'secret';
GRANT readaccess TO xyz;
```

But this is only working for the public schemata. Lets assume, i create a new schemata called "new_schema", the user xyz don't have readaccess to this this schema.

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO readaccess;
```

is creating readaccess to all future tables inside a specific schemata, but not for future schematas.

Long story short: How can i give readaccess to all existing **and** future schematas for a specific user?

Comment: If you are using Postgres 14, you can simply grant the `pg_read_all_data` role to user xyz.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sadly i'm forced to use `PostgreSQL-Version 11`